# What is the difference between not-null checks in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

There are some ways to fulfill a null-checking in Kotlin:

1.

```
if(myVar != null) {
    foo(myVar)
}
```

2.

```
myVar?.let { 
    foo(it)
}
```

3.

```
myVar?.run { 
    foo(this)
}
```

What are the difference between these ways?

Are there any reasons (performance, best practice, code style etc.) why I should prefer on way over the other?

Answer (score 1):

!! is to tell the compiler that I am sure the value of the variable is not null, and if it is null throw a null pointer exception (NPE) where as ?. is to tell the compiler that I am not sure if the value of the variable is null or not, if it is null do not throw any null pointer.

Another way of using a nullable property is safe call operator ?.
This calls the method if the property is not null or returns null if that property is null without throwing an NPE (null pointer exception).

```
nullableVariable?.someMethodCall()
```

Answer (score 0):

All three code are behave same null check in operation-wise.

?. is used for chain operations.

```
 bob?.department?.head?.name // if any of the properties in it is null it returns null
```

To perform a chain operation only for non-null values, you can use the safe call operator together with let

```
myVar?.let { 
foo(it)
}
```

the above code is good for code style and performance

more details refer  [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Answer (score 0):

The ways 2 and 3 are more idiomatic for Kotlin. Both functions are quite similar. There is little difference with argument passing.

For example, we have a nullable variable:

```
var canBeNull: String? = null
```

When you working with `T.run` you work with extension function calling and you pass `this` in the closure.

```
    canBeNull?.run {
        println(length) // `this` could be omitted
    }
```

When you call `T.let` you can use it like lambda argument `it`.

```
    canBeNull?.let {
        myString -> println(myString.length) // You could convert `it` to some other name
    }
```

A good [article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) about Kotlin standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

All three are roughly equivalent.

The `if` case is more like most other languages, and so many developers may find it easier to read.

However, one difference is that the `if` case will read the value of `myVar` twice: once for the check, and again when passing it to `foo()`.  That makes a difference, because if `myVar` is a property (i.e. something that could potentially be changed by another thread), then the compiler will warn that it could have been set to null *after* the check.  If that's a problem (e.g. because `foo()` expects a non-null parameter), then you'll need to use one of the other cases.

For that reason, the `let` case has become fairly common practice in Kotlin.  (The `run` case does just about the same thing, but for some reason isn't as popular for this sort of thing.  I don't know why.)

Another way around it is to assign `myVar` to a temporary value, test that, and then use that.  That's also more like other languages, but it's more verbose; many people prefer the conciseness of the `let` case — especially when `myVar` is actually a complicated expression.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in your question don't show the true reason to decide.

First of all, since you're not using the return value of `foo`, you should use neither `let` nor `run`. Your choice is between `also` and `apply`.

Second, since you already have the result you want to null-check in a variable, the difference fades. This is a better motivating example:

```
complexCall(calculateArg1(), calculateArg2())?.also {
    results.add(it)
}
```

as opposed to

```
val result = complexCall(calculateArg1(), calculateArg2())
if (result != null) {
    results.add(result)
}
```

The second example declares an identifier, `result`, which is now available to the rest of the lexical scope, even though you're done with it in just one line.

The first example, on the other hand, keeps everything self-contained and when you go on reading the rest of the code, you are 100% confident that you don't have to keep in mind the meaning of `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin have new features with NullPoint-Exception as Compare to Java.

Basically When we do Coding in Java , then we have to Check with !! in every Flied.

But in Kotlin, it is Easy way to Implement First

as Like,

Suppose, in Kotlin

var response:Json?=Null

response:Json?.let {

this part will handle automatic if response is Not Null....then this Block start Executing }?.run {
This is Nullable But, where we Can put Warring } So, I am Suggest you Guys to Start Work in Kotlin with this Features Provided by Kotlin.

(Flied)?.let { Not Null Value Comes Under }?.run{ Null Value Code }

This will Handle to NullPoint Exception or Protect You App for Crash

Comment: please remove duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

**What you want to achieve**

What you want to achieve is that the Kotlin compiler does a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) on the variable you are working with.

In all of your three examples, the compiler can do that.

Example:

```
if(myVar != null) {
    foo(myVar) // smart cast: the compiler knows, that myVar can never be null here
}
```

**The choice**

Which one of the options to use, is really a matter of style. What you should not do is mix it up to often. Use one and stick to it.

You don't need to worry about performance since [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) and [run](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) are inlined (see [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions)). This means that their code (body) is copied to the call site at compile time so there is no runtime overhead.